# Specifying dynamic type for generic method

Tags: c#, generics

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I've not found what I'm after - everything seems to be talking about ILists.

At the moment I am calling methods and passing the type as a generic which works as you would expect but is causing code duplication. I would like to be able to do

```
Type.MakeGenericParameter()
```

But this requires a parameter. I'm calling a generic method, not creating an object. The generic method is not contained with in a generic object.

How can I do something along the lines of

```
Type desiredType = typeof(IPendingProduct);
...
Product.Save<desiredType>(instance);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
typeof(Product).GetMethod("Save").MakeGenericMethod(desiredType)
        .Invoke(null, new object[] {instance});
```

not nice, huh?

Note this also assumes that `Save` is public + static, and has no collisions with overloads.

Comment: Yeah right - that or code duplication... hard decision. Cheers Marc. Assumptions were correct.